# How to check if class was properly mapped in Zend_amf?

Tags: apache-flex, zend-framework, amf, zend-amf

I've successfully configured AMF on the flex side. The client is sending messages, but in return it always get empty response ( headers, but no body).

How to debug index.php? How to check if classes are mapped correctly?

Here is my `index.php`:

```
use Project\Entity\Product;

require_once('Zend/Amf/Server.php');
require_once(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/Amf/') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'AmfService.php');

$server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
$server->setClass('AmfService');
$server->setClassMap("Product", "Product");

echo($server -> handle());
```

and `AmfService.php`:

```
use Project\Entity\Product;

class AmfService {

 public function getProducts(){
    $result = array();

    $product = new Product();

    $product->description = "desc";
    $product->title_pl = "title";

    $result[] = $product;

    return $result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my problem lied on the `Flex` side rather than `php`.

My problem wast that I've omit `source` attribute in `RemoteObject` declaration. Now it works perfectly :)